# Отсортировать данные в ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf

Помогите отсортировать данные в листбокс.

Найти элемент TextBlock Text которого будет равняться выбраному Combobox item, после чего удалить лишние ListBoxItems и оставить только те, что содержат выбранный Combobox item

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string text = (sender as ComboBox).SelectedItem as string;

        foreach (var realmBlock in FindVisualChildren<TextBlock>(this))
        {
            if (realmBlock.Text == text)
            {

                ArrayList arList = new ArrayList();
                foreach (object obj in charList.Items)
                {
                    arList.Add(obj);
                }
                //arList.Sort();

                charList.Items.Clear();
                foreach (object obj in arList)
                {
                    charList.Items.Add(obj);
                }


            }
        }



    }
```

Не совсем понимаю, как это сделать

Код listbox

```
<ListBox x:Name="charList"
                             Width="326"
                             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                             Background="{x:Null}"
                             BorderBrush="Transparent"
                             ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItem}"
                             ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource CharTemplate}"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                             SelectedIndex="0"
                             Padding="0,5,0,0"
                             VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel">
                        <ListBox.Resources>
                            <DataTemplate x:Key="CharTemplate">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="125" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Image x:Name="listCharPortait"
                                           Width="80"
                                           Height="50"
                                           Source="{Binding ImageLink}"
                                           Stretch="Fill" />
                                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"
                                                MaxWidth="174"
                                                MaxHeight="100"
                                                Margin="-5,25,0,25"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                                                    TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold">
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="nameBlock"
                                                       Text="{Binding Realms}"
                                                       TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                                       TextWrapping="Wrap">
                                                <TextBlock.Foreground>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Opacity="0.5"
                                                                     Color="#FF959595" />
                                                </TextBlock.Foreground>
                                            </TextBlock>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <TextBlock FontFamily="/Launcher;component/Resources/#Blizzard"
                                                       FontSize="14"
                                                       Foreground="White"
                                                       Text="{Binding Title,
                                                                      FallbackValue=Title}"
                                                       TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                                       TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.Resources>
                    </ListBox>
```

Comment: @VladD не посмотрите?

Comment: Не совсем понятно как у вас расположены визуальные элементы. У вас TextBlock вложен в ComboBoxItem? А ListBox отдельный элемент с отдельной коллекцией? Так или нет?

Comment: Обновила вопрос

Comment: Вам очень срочно надо? Или можно до утра подождать?

Comment: Как Вам удобно, вторые сутки с этим бьюсь, если к утру до меня не дойдет, была бы рада Вашему ответу

Comment: Утро вечера мудренее, я вам в первой половине дня отпишу.

Comment: Буду рада, но полагаюсь на свои силы)

Comment: @Bulson, Добрый день! у вас нет варианта для решения моей проблемы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По-хорошему лучше бы вы использовали байдинг. Тогда все было бы гораздо проще. Два свойства типа `ObservableCollection<T>`  для `ComboBox` и для `ListBox`. А для `SelectedItem` свойство `CurrentElement`. При выборе элемента можно было было бы использовать LINQ на свойстве коллекции для `ListBox`.

Comment: Вы не могли бы дать код, я не совсем понимаю, что Вы имеете ввиду

Comment: Вот здесь можете скачать: https://yadi.sk/d/eEOKgoCXwoM8g

Comment: Посмотрите эту версию, там я сделал с ViewModel и с командами
https://yadi.sk/d/ud7mV3Fbwqr6G

Comment: хорошо, спасибо!  Домой приду, попробую

Comment: К сожалению не смогла разобраться в Вашем варианте, у меня есть различия, и я никак не могу сделать по примеру((